# Why is "och" (and) not spelled "og" in Swedish?

Tags: orthography, written-language, germanic-languages, swedish

For example, here is the word for "I" in the Old Norse dialects.

- Old East Norse = Ja**k**
- Old West Norse = E**k**

These words became, with a natural evolution, the following:

- Icelandic = É**g**
- Faroese = E**g**
- Bokmål = Je**g**
- Nynorsk = E**g**
- Danish = Je**g**
- Swedish = Ja**g**
- Elfdalian  = I**g**

Here is the word for "and" in Old Norse (both dialects):

- Old Norse = O**k**

And again, the same changes occured, except for Swedish:

- Icelandic = O**g**
- Faroese = O**g**
- Bokmål = O**g**
- Nynorsk = O**g**
- Danish = O**g**
- Elfdalian  = O**g**
- Swedish = O**ch** (pronounced like a **k**)

Why didn't this change occur in Swedish?

The same thing applies for others words like "you" ("þi**k**" became "de**g**", "þi**g**", "te**g**" and "di**g**").

Comment: Compare German "auch" (*also, too, as well*) also Berliner "och" (also *also*), Dutch "ook", English archaic "eke". Greek "kai" (end) has a velar, too (read kaigh, hence ogh?); Cognate "augment" and, due to the PIE root glossed "increase", I suppose, German "aufwerten" (*enhence, augment*) under influence of "auf" (up, open) ...

Answer (score 7):

In the earliest Swedish written using the Latin alphabet, such as the [Äldre Västgötalagen](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:V%C3%A4stg%C3%B6talagen_blad_21.jpg) from about 1250, the word is spelt 'ok'. It seems to have changed to 'och' during the later middle ages or early modern period, when 'decorative spelling' (*[dekorativ stavning](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekorativ_stavning)*) became popular. One possibility is that the modern spelling is therefore a relic of decorative spelling.

However, in contradiction to that, the Swedish Etymological Dictionary [states](http://runeberg.org/svetym/0628.html) that "*Stavningen* och *bevarar minnet av ett forntida uttal med* ach-*ljud*" ("the spelling *och* preserves the memory of an ancient pronunciation using the *ach* sound" [that is, a velar or uvular fricative]).

Comment: Do we have reason to believe that "och" used to be pronounced with a velar fricative in Swedish?

Answer (score 3):

When unstressed, Swedish "och" is phonetically [ɔ], which isn't any different from Norwegian "og" [ɔ]. Referencing Danish is really not that informative as Danish has voiced most of its consonants so that even if it had "*ok", it would've gone to "og" either way (a generic example: Danish vs. Swedish *bog* & *bok* 'book').  My thoughts on it are that stressed "och" preserved the hard plosive while its unstressed variant lenited it to [ɣ] which was lost almost everywhere. Irregular sound changes, sure, but those are abundant and particularly full of holes.

Comment: They are very close but i wouldn't say they are not different. Are you thinking of dialectal forms maybe? Western Swedish? If we speak of Rikssvenska then there is a difference between och and og.

Comment: @Midas; my apologies as I was rather unclear; I meant (at the time) to say that their etymology isn't any different (as far as I understand/understood it at the time). The difference in usage today are later developments that are fully legitimate.